# Windows 8: Delayed PIN or picture logon after booting

Tags: windows-8, login, delay, pin

After rebooting my Windows 8 laptop, I can instantly login with my password, as I would expect.

However, if I use my PIN instead, the system mostly freezes for about one minute: The input box disappears, the "back"-Button becomes unresponsive. After one minute, the login is executed as expected.

Some things still work in this "freeze": I can switch the keyboard layout, and this "slide-up-to-unlock"-lockscreen engages after a few seconds of inactivity.

This problem only occurs directly after a reboot. After hibernation or logging off, there is no delay, and if I reboot and wait a few minutes before logging on, there is no delay, too.

The picture password login has the same problem, while using the password works fine.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Windows is having a hard time finding the correct PIN or picture password solution to compare it to the one you entered. I can't say for sure, but my guess is that Windows goes get that PIN/solution from the Microsoft servers, to ensure it's synced with your Microsoft account, and it's very long for some reason. And only does it upon the first login after turning it on. Try logging in when no Internet access is available, or from a local account, and if it's faster, well, sounds like I was right.

If not, well, there might be an issue with how those things are set/saved on your computer. Try deleting both the PIN and the picture password, and setting them back again after a computer reboot.

If that changes nothing, try to find another reason why the PIN/picture password solution would be so hard to find. What makes data hard to find? Try a defrag, maybe?

Maybe there's an app on your computer that launches automatically even before you log in that slows the process, either by interfering with it or by just taking all of the available resources. It could even be a malware. You might want to do a scan on your computer.

Comment: Going offline, switching to a local account or disabling and re-enabling the PIN did not help. My disk is defragmented. I don't know of any third-party-software that could interfere here. Any more ideas?

Comment: Okay... Weird. You could try the option in Windows to repair the OS (that's in General in the modern-UI settings), but I don't know anymore where to head. Maybe it's literally a programming fault? Sounds doubtful since we'd heard about it, but... Oh well, if I were having mysterious issues like those, I think I'd see it as a sign my computer requires formating. But this is kind of like fleeing the problem, eh?

Comment: Exactly, and I don't want to flee - especially since I already did a clean install of Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem after a clean install of Windows 8 and then an upgrade (from the Store) to Windows 8.1. What did the trick for me was to open Services management window (services.msc) and change startup type for Credential Manager service from Manual to Automatic.